# Segmentation fault(core dumped) in CPP

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault

I am confused a bit. I narrowed down it to:

Why having this line:

`Node *root, *rootSafe = NULL;`

give error:

```
Segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

While just switching it like below:

`Node *rootSafe, *root = NULL;`

runs perfect.

Here is the code, you can test.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *left, *right;
    Node(int d){
        this->data = d;
        this->left = this->right = NULL;
    }
};
Node *newNode(int d){
    Node *temp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = d;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}
void printInorder(Node *root){
    if(root == NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{
        printInorder(root->left);
        cout << "--" << root->data;
        printInorder(root->right);
    }
}
int main()
{
    //cout << "Hello World";
    Node *rootSafe, *root = NULL;
    int arr[] = {5, 3, 1, 4, 6};
    int sizeArr = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    
    for(auto i = 0; i < sizeArr; i++){
        if(root == NULL){
            rootSafe = newNode(arr[i]);
            root = rootSafe;
        }
        else{
            while(root != NULL){
                if(arr[i] < root->data){//Move left
                    if(root->left == NULL){
                        root->left = newNode(arr[i]);
                        root = NULL;
                    }
                    else{
                        root = root->left;
                    }
                }
                else{//Move right
                    if(root->right == NULL){
                        root->right = newNode(arr[i]);
                        root = NULL;
                    }
                    else{
                        root = root->right;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        root = rootSafe;
    }
    
    cout << "\n Print Inorder: ----"; printInorder(rootSafe);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use malloc in C++?

Comment: Was just testing, I can do without it, as struct Node has constructor.

Comment: So, what is unusual about this, you should initialize _all_ declared pointers to be safe, i.e. `Node *root = NULL, *rootSafe = NULL;`. BTW, this is C code, not C++. C++ uses `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Uninitialized variables retains whatever value that is in their memory cell, which makes *root have a value in the faulty case.

Comment: I see, I am doing several mistakes. Thank you sklott for correcting !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without fiddling with your code, I think this:

```
Node *root, *rootSafe = NULL;
```

Doesn't do what you think it does. Do you think it sets both to NULL? It doesn't. root gets some random value and rootSafe gets NULL.

This might be what you really want:

```
Node *root = NULL, *rootSafe = NULL;
```

Frankly, I personally hate (and it's against coding conventions at some work places) specifying multiple variables on the same line. You will not find this in my code. Instead, you will see:

```
Node * root = nullptr;
Node * rootSafe = nullptr;
```

Note also that in modern C++, NULL is not a pointer. Get in the habit of using nullptr.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `root` here:

```
        if(root == NULL){
```

Your original declaration

```
Node *root, *rootSafe = NULL;
```

doesn't initialize `root`, leaving it with indeterminate value. Therefore, `root` with some random invalid value may be dereferenced and it may lead to Segmentation Fault.

To avoid this, you should initialize `root` before using that.

It can be done in declaration:

```
Node *root = NULL, *rootSafe = NULL;
```

Or before the loop:

```
    root = NULL;
    for(auto i = 0; i < sizeArr; i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Node *root, *rootSafe = NULL;
Node *rootSafe, *root = NULL;
```

The first line leaves root uninitialized. This causes undefined behaviour while access root.

The second line leaves rootSafe uninitialized but the var later initialized `rootSafe = newNode(arr[i]);`.